# Two Eclipses on same Maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, m2e

I have one single external installation of Maven 3.0.4 and two Eclipses (Juno and Indigo) referring it in their m2e settings.

Also I have one single user setting file which describes one single local repository. Both Eclipses refer it.

I have a problems with Maven which can be suspected as conflict between Eclipses.

For example, one of Eclipses (say Indigo) can be blind concerning some global repository (say central). This means that it's subnodes in "Maven Repositories" view of eclipse are empty

[image]

Updating/Rebuilding index does not help and probably does nothing since ends very fast.

Reloading settings also does not help.

The question is: is it possible to use one single maven with several Eclipses? Is it possible that principal multiuser system does not support multiusing?

Where the data can be corrupted?

Answer (score 2):

You would be better of ignoring the Eclipse specific installs of Maven.
I have found that relying on pre-installed software on Eclipse, leads to problems for the following reasons.

You will never know exactly what version of maven they have installed and why (finding out is harder than installing yourself)

If it won't run in the IDE, what chance will your build server have (and you will meet those problems in Jenkins or your CI server when it comes to release time)

It is very easy to install Maven yourself and run it from the commandline and less problematic.

http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

If there is a team of developers using maven think about hosting it yourself on a nexus server.